# I keep using this same chunk of code over and over. How do I consolidate it?

Tags: swift, struct, dry, subclassing

Being the Swift noob that I am, I find myself copying and pasting code. I know I'm supposed to use the DRY method and not do this, but this particular bit of code has me stumped. I tried creating a struct to hold it, but the struct threw all sorts of errors. I don't quite understand classes and how I would subclass it, and so maybe that's the solution. I just don't know how to do it? Or maybe an extension?

Anyway, here is the code I keep copying and pasting in each new view controller:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit

class Step3JobSummaryVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

...

var sourceVCIdentity = "setup"

var initialLaunch = true
let playerVC = AVPlayerViewController()
let video = Video.step3JobsSummary

...


// ------------------------
// Autoplay Video Functions
// ------------------------

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if initialLaunch == true {
        showUnplayedVideo()
        initialLaunch = false
    }

    Video.updatePlaybackTime(playerVC: playerVC, videoURL: video.url, firebaseVideoID: video.firebaseID)
}

func showUnplayedVideo() {

    // 1. get current video data
    Video.getFirebaseData(firebaseVideoID: video.firebaseID) { (playbackTime, watched) in

        if !watched {

            // 2. show setup video popup on first load
            guard let videoURL = URL(string: self.video.url) else { print("url error"); return }
            let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)

            self.playerVC.player = player

            // 3. fast forward to where user left off (if applicable)
            player.seek(to: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(playbackTime, 1))

            // 4. dismiss the player once the video is over and update Firebase
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                                   selector: #selector(self.playerDidFinishPlaying),
                                                   name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                                   object: self.playerVC.player?.currentItem)

            self.present(self.playerVC, animated: true) {
                self.playerVC.player?.play()
            }
        }
    }
}

@objc func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification) {
    self.playerVC.dismiss(animated: true)
    Video.updateFirebase(firebaseVideoID: video.firebaseID)
}
```

Any help would be great. I'm just trying to learn :-)

**EDIT #1**

This is my attempt at an extension. I simplified and refactored my code, but as before, it's giving me an error. This time the error is 'extensions must not contain stored properties'. So how do I access the AVPlayerController?!?

```
extension UIViewController {

let playerVC = AVPlayerViewController()

func showUnplayedVideo(video: Video) {

    // 1. get current video data
    Video.getFirebaseData(firebaseVideoID: video.firebaseID) { (playbackTime, watched) in

        if !watched {
            // 2. show setup video popup on first load
            guard let videoURL = URL(string: video.url) else { print("url error"); return }
            let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)

            self.playerVC.player = player

            // 3. fast forward to where user left off (if applicable)
            player.seek(to: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(playbackTime, 1))

            // 4. dismiss the player once the video is over and update Firebase
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                                   object: playerVC.player?.currentItem,
                                                   queue: .main) { (notification) in

                                                    self.playerDidFinishPlaying(note: notification as NSNotification)

            self.present(self.playerVC, animated: true) {
                self.playerVC.player?.play()
            }
        }
    }
}

    func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification, video: Video) {
        self.playerVC.dismiss(animated: true)
        Video.updateFirebase(firebaseVideoID: video.firebaseID)
    }
}
```

**EDIT #2**

So I got the code to compile without any errors, but now it's not firing. Aargh.

```
extension UIViewController {

func showUnplayedVideo(playerVC: AVPlayerViewController, video: Video) {

    print("does this code even fire?")

    // 1. get current video data
    Video.getFirebaseData(firebaseVideoID: video.firebaseID) { (playbackTime, watched) in

        if !watched {
            // 2. show setup video popup on first load
            guard let videoURL = URL(string: video.url) else { print("url error"); return }
            let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)

            playerVC.player = player

            // 3. fast forward to where user left off (if applicable)
            player.seek(to: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(playbackTime, 1))

            // 4. dismiss the player once the video is over and update Firebase
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                                   object: playerVC.player?.currentItem,
                                                   queue: .main) { (notification) in

                                                    self.playerDidFinishPlaying(playerVC: playerVC, note: notification as NSNotification, video: video)

                                                    self.present(playerVC, animated: true) {
                                                        playerVC.player?.play()
                                                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

func playerDidFinishPlaying(playerVC: AVPlayerViewController, note: NSNotification, video: Video) {
    playerVC.dismiss(animated: true)
    Video.updateFirebase(firebaseVideoID: video.firebaseID)
}
}
```

Why won't this work?

Comment: I've posted an answer for the original question, but just as a side note - I'd advise against the extension method for this as it's not something all UIViewController's really need. It's custom logic that would be better served packaged in a specific class. However, I don't see why your extension would not work - can you post how you are invoking it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using a more traditional inheritance model?

```
class VideoPlayingBaseController: : UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if initialLaunch == true {
        showUnplayedVideo()
        initialLaunch = false
    }

    Video.updatePlaybackTime(playerVC: playerVC, videoURL: video.url, firebaseVideoID: video.firebaseID)
}

func showUnplayedVideo() {

    // 1. get current video data
    Video.getFirebaseData(firebaseVideoID: video.firebaseID) { (playbackTime, watched) in

        if !watched {

            // 2. show setup video popup on first load
            guard let videoURL = URL(string: self.video.url) else { print("url error"); return }
            let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)

            self.playerVC.player = player

            // 3. fast forward to where user left off (if applicable)
            player.seek(to: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(playbackTime, 1))

            // 4. dismiss the player once the video is over and update Firebase
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                                   selector: #selector(self.playerDidFinishPlaying),
                                                   name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                                   object: self.playerVC.player?.currentItem)

            self.present(self.playerVC, animated: true) {
                self.playerVC.player?.play()
            }
        }
    }
}

@objc func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification) {
    self.playerVC.dismiss(animated: true)
    Video.updateFirebase(firebaseVideoID: video.firebaseID)
}


}
```

Then have your classes that use it:

```
class Step3JobSummaryVC: VideoPlayingBaseController {
 //more code here
}
```

Comment: This seems very simple. I'll try this and get back with you.

Comment: Okay, so I got it to work. Nice! But I'm still a little sticky on the override of `viewDidAppear`. I think I'll pull that out in case other VCs have to access the `viewDidAppear` for other things.

Comment: And yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. I wanted a way to extend the VC to include new functionality without it becoming overly complex. Thank you.

Comment: You should prefer composition over inheritance. This idea completely falls apart the moment you want to reuse some other piece of functionality over some of your view controllers. You can't inherit from multiple classes.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with defining a protocol for your functionality something like this:

```
protocol VideoPlayable {
    func showUnplayedVideo(playerVC: AVPlayerViewController, video: Video)
}
```

And then add a default implementation to it

```
extension VideoPlayable where Self: UIViewController {

    func showUnplayedVideo(playerVC: AVPlayerViewController, video: Video) {

       print("does this code even fire?")

       // 1. get current video data
       Video.getFirebaseData(firebaseVideoID: video.firebaseID) { (playbackTime, watched) in

            if !watched {
            // 2. show setup video popup on first load
                guard let videoURL = URL(string: video.url) else { print("url error"); return }
                let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)

                playerVC.player = player

                // 3. fast forward to where user left off (if applicable)
                player.seek(to: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(playbackTime, 1))

                // 4. dismiss the player once the video is over and update Firebase
                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                                   object: playerVC.player?.currentItem,
                                                   queue: .main) { (notification) in

                    self.playerDidFinishPlaying(playerVC: playerVC, note: notification as NSNotification, video: video)

                }

                self.present(playerVC, animated: true) {
                    playerVC.player?.play()
                }

            }
        }
    }

    private func playerDidFinishPlaying(playerVC: AVPlayerViewController, note: NSNotification, video: Video) {
        playerVC.dismiss(animated: true)
        Video.updateFirebase(firebaseVideoID: video.firebaseID)
    }
}
```

Thanks to this when you add the VideoPlayable protocol to a controller you will have your custom functionality available, and other controllers that shouldn't have the functionality won't have the access to this method.
Also if you really want to have access to the method

```
func playerDidFinishPlaying(playerVC: AVPlayerViewController, note: NSNotification, video: Video)
```

Add it to the protocol and remove the private statement from the implementation.

And you video player wasn't being shown because you added the presenting of the player into the notification block.

Also, consider adding proper self handling to your blocks. Right now I think its possible that the self can be caught in the blocks.

Just to let you know the statement
    where Self: UIViewController
Limits the access of the implementation to UIViewControllers, so if you add the protocol to a UIView subclass you wont get access to the default implementation. You will then need to add a new one :) this prevents the missing of the protocol in places you dont want it to be used.

Comment: Okay, I'll try this.

Comment: The `video player` in the wrong block was just a typo. Thanks for pointing that out! Silly issues when you're copying and pasting code and troubleshooting. :-p

Comment: Ultimately, because of my lack of experience, I'm going to shy away from the protocol and stick with the subclassing. Thanks for you answer, tho.

Answer (score 1):

You can just move all the reused code into a separate class:

```
class Step3JobSummaryVC: UIViewController {

    let videoPlayer = VideoPlayer(video: Video.step3JobsSummary)

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        videoPlayer.start(on: self)
    }
}

final
class VideoPlayer {
    private var initialLaunch: Bool = true
    private let playerVC = AVPlayerViewController()
    private let video: Video

    init(video: Video) {
        self.video = video
    }

    func start(on viewController: UIViewController) {
        if initialLaunch == true {
            showUnplayedVideo(on: viewController)
            initialLaunch = false
        }

        Video.updatePlaybackTime(playerVC: playerVC, videoURL: video.url, firebaseVideoID: video.firebaseID)
    }

    func showUnplayedVideo(on viewController: UIViewController) {

        // 1. get current video data
        Video.getFirebaseData(firebaseVideoID: video.firebaseID) { (playbackTime, watched) in

            if !watched {

                // 2. show setup video popup on first load
                guard let videoURL = URL(string: self.video.url) else { print("url error"); return }
                let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)

                self.playerVC.player = player

                // 3. fast forward to where user left off (if applicable)
                player.seek(to: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(playbackTime, preferredTimescale: 1))

                // 4. dismiss the player once the video is over and update Firebase
                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                                       selector: #selector(self.playerDidFinishPlaying),
                                                       name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                                       object: self.playerVC.player?.currentItem)

                viewController.present(self.playerVC, animated: true) {
                    self.playerVC.player?.play()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification) {
        self.playerVC.dismiss(animated: true)
        Video.updateFirebase(firebaseVideoID: video.firebaseID)
    }
}
```